# solve Str8ts with prolog, labeling after set the constraints(domain)

Tags: prolog, constraints

I want to solve [str8ts](http://www.str8ts.com/) with prolog

There are 3 constraints which I set for all lists:

1. **Constraint 1:** each list --> `all_different(list)`
2. **Constraint 2:** each list --> `list ins 1..9`
3. **Constraint 3:** each list --> white groups between(or before one black, or              after a black) 2 black fields have to be **gapless**

After I set the constraint I call `labeling([ff],PuzzleVariable)`.

**the problem is to set constraint 3**
let me explain with my code.
my code:

First I enter puzzle with a list of 81 elements (*A1,B1,C1, are the numbers and IB11,IB12... shows if its black field or not*):

```
puzzle([[A1,IB11],[A2,IB12],[A3,IB13], [A4,IB14],[A5,IB15],[A6,IB16],[A7,IB17],[A8,IB18],[A9,IB19],
  [B1,IB21],[B2,IB22],[B3,IB23], [B4,IB24],[B5,IB25],[B6,IB26],[B7,IB27],[B8,IB28],[B9,IB29],
   [C1,IB31],[C2,IB32],[C3,IB33], [C4,IB34],[C5,IB35],[C6,IB36],[C7,IB37],[C8,IB38],[C9,IB39],

   [D1,IB41],[D2,IB42],[D3,IB43], [D4,IB44],[D5,IB45],[D6,IB46],[D7,IB47],[D8,IB48],[D9,IB49],
   [E1,IB51],[E2,IB52],[E3,IB53], [E4,IB54],[E5,IB55],[E6,IB56],[E7,IB57],[E8,IB58],[E9,IB59],
   [F1,IB61],[F2,IB62],[F3,IB63], [F4,IB64],[F5,IB65],[F6,IB66],[F7,IB67],[F8,IB68],[F9,IB69],

   [G1,IB71],[G2,IB72],[G3,IB73], [G4,IB74],[G5,IB75],[G6,IB76],[G7,IB77],[G8,IB78],[G9,IB79],
   [H1,IB81],[H2,IB82],[H3,IB83], [H4,IB84],[H5,IB85],[H6,IB86],[H7,IB87],[H8,IB88],[H9,IB89],
   [I1,IB91],[I2,IB92],[I3,IB93], [I4,IB94],[I5,IB95],[I6,IB96],[I7,IB97],[I8,IB98],[I9,IB99]])
```

after, i want to set the 3 constraints for each row and column of the list, so i call "pruefen" for all rows and column:

```
 %CHECK ROWS
    pruefen([[A1,IB11],[A2,IB12],[A3,IB13], [A4,IB14],[A5,IB15],[A6,IB16],[A7,IB17],[A8,IB18],[A9,IB19]]),
    pruefen([[B1,IB21],[B2,IB22],[B3,IB23], [B4,IB24],[B5,IB25],[B6,IB26],[B7,IB27],[B8,IB28],[B9,IB29]]),
    pruefen([[C1,IB31],[C2,IB32],[C3,IB33], [C4,IB34],[C5,IB35],[C6,IB36],[C7,IB37],[C8,IB38],[C9,IB39]]),
    pruefen([[D1,IB41],[D2,IB42],[D3,IB43], [D4,IB44],[D5,IB45],[D6,IB46],[D7,IB47],[D8,IB48],[D9,IB49]]),
    pruefen([[E1,IB51],[E2,IB52],[E3,IB53], [E4,IB54],[E5,IB55],[E6,IB56],[E7,IB57],[E8,IB58],[E9,IB59]]),
    pruefen([[F1,IB61],[F2,IB62],[F3,IB63], [F4,IB64],[F5,IB65],[F6,IB66],[F7,IB67],[F8,IB68],[F9,IB69]]),
    pruefen([[G1,IB71],[G2,IB72],[G3,IB73], [G4,IB74],[G5,IB75],[G6,IB76],[G7,IB77],[G8,IB78],[G9,IB79]]),
    pruefen([[H1,IB81],[H2,IB82],[H3,IB83], [H4,IB84],[H5,IB85],[H6,IB86],[H7,IB87],[H8,IB88],[H9,IB89]]),
    pruefen([[I1,IB91],[I2,IB92],[I3,IB93], [I4,IB94],[I5,IB95],[I6,IB96],[I7,IB97],[I8,IB98],[I9,IB99]]),
    %CHECK COLUMNS
    pruefen([[A1,IB11],[B1,IB21],[C1,IB31], [D1,IB41],[E1,IB51],[F1,IB61],[G1,IB71],[H1,IB81],[I1,IB91]]),
    pruefen([[A2,IB12],[B2,IB22],[C2,IB32], [D2,IB42],[E2,IB52],[F2,IB62],[G2,IB72],[H2,IB82],[I2,IB92]]),
    pruefen([[A3,IB13],[B3,IB23],[C3,IB33], [D3,IB43],[E3,IB53],[F3,IB63],[G3,IB73],[H3,IB83],[I3,IB93]]),
    pruefen([[A4,IB14],[B4,IB24],[C4,IB34], [D4,IB44],[E4,IB54],[F4,IB64],[G4,IB74],[H4,IB84],[I4,IB94]]),
    pruefen([[A5,IB15],[B5,IB25],[C5,IB35], [D5,IB45],[E5,IB55],[F5,IB65],[G5,IB75],[H5,IB85],[I5,IB95]]),
    pruefen([[A6,IB16],[B6,IB26],[C6,IB36], [D6,IB46],[E6,IB56],[F6,IB66],[G6,IB76],[H6,IB86],[I6,IB96]]),
    pruefen([[A7,IB17],[B7,IB27],[C7,IB37], [D7,IB47],[E7,IB57],[F7,IB67],[G7,IB77],[H7,IB87],[I7,IB97]]),
    pruefen([[A8,IB18],[B8,IB28],[C8,IB38], [D8,IB48],[E8,IB58],[F8,IB68],[G8,IB78],[H8,IB88],[I8,IB98]]),
    pruefen([[A9,IB19],[B9,IB29],[C9,IB39], [D9,IB49],[E9,IB59],[F9,IB69],[G9,IB79],[H9,IB89],[I9,IB99]]),
```

SO, I call pruefen for the lists.

First I exclude all field which are black and undefined, because I dont need/want set constraint for them:

```
  %exclude black and undefined lists
  exclude(isBlackAndEmpty,L,NewList),
  %Constraint 1 and 2, every list ins 1..9 and all different(list)
  constraintsFestlegen(NewList),
```

the predicate for exclude:

`isBlackAndEmpty([Variable|IsBlack]):-
  IsBlack=:=1,
  var(Variable).`

the predicate to set the constraints:

```
    %set constraints for whole list(black and undefined excluded)
  variablenListeErstellen([],Variablen):-
      %jede Liste darf nur aus Zahlen von 1..9 bestehen
      Variablen ins 1..9,
      %es dürfen in der Liste keine Zahlen doppelt vorkommen
      %bibliothek von SWI-Prolog Bibliothek clpfd
      all_different(Variablen).
```

So, this was for constraints  1 and 2.

---

**Constraint 3**: I split every list into groups of white fiels.

predicate to create the groups:

```
%ausstiegspunkt für eine leere liste
  listGroupConstraints([]).

  %for a list with a black field
  listGroupConstraints(List):-
  append(Prefix, [[_,1]|Rest],List),
  %creates one dimensional list
  createOneDimensional(Prefix,OneDimensionalList),
  %rekursiv
  listGroupConstraints(Rest).

   %for a list without a black field
  listGroupConstraints(List):-
  %convert to one dimensional list
  createOneDimensional(List,OneDimensionalList),
  %set constraint for one dimensional list
  setGroupConstraints(OneDimensionalList).
```

the setGroupConstraints i use to set Constraint 3 for all groups of white fields.

predicate to check for gapless and set constraint 3:

```
  %check if group is gapless,
  listl(L) :-
    [Fst,Lst] ins 1..9,
    Fst #=< Lst,
    Len #= Lst - Fst + 1,
    length(L, Len),
    label([Fst,Lst]),
    L ins Fst..Lst,
    all_different(L).
```

after i set the 3 constraints, i filter my whole inputlist to labeling only white fields:

exclude(isBlack,List,ExcludedList)

```
 %check if black
  isBlack([Variable|IsBlack]):-
  IsBlack=:=1.

   %create one dimensional list from two dimensional list for labeling all
  %get the first variables from list
  createOneDimensionalForLabeling([],Variablen):-
  print(Variablen),
  labeling([ff],Variablen).
  createOneDimensionalForLabeling([X|Rest],Variablen):-
  listeInListe(X,Variable,IsBlack),
  append(Variablen,[Variable],MyList),
  createOneDimensionalForLabeling(Rest,MyList).
```

But on labeling i get: **ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated**

someone know the problem?

Example input:

```
puzzle([[9,1],[6,0],[8,0],[1,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[4,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,1],[_,1],[4,0],[_,0],[_,0],[7,1],[_,1],[5,0],[_,1],[_,1],[_,0],[3,0],[_,0],[_,1],[_,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[4,0],[6,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,1],[3,0],[_,0],[_,1],[_,0],[5,0],[8,0],[_,0],[_,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,1],[_,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,1],[5,1],[_,0],[_,1],[_,1],[5,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,1],[4,1],[1,0],[_,0],[_,0],[7,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[1,1]]).
```

**EDITED**
Is it possible that i delete the domain from variables?
When i create the one dimensional list out of my two dimensional list. on the call i that the variable list has a domain: `lists:append([6, 8, 1, _G5{clpfd = ...}, _G6{clpfd = ...}, _G7{clpfd = ...}, 4|...],`

But after finishing the one dimension list, the variable look like:

```
[6,8,1,_G5,_G6,_G7,4,_G8,_G9,_G10,4,...]
```

**EDIT 2**

If i call `constraintsFestlegen([[A,0],[B,0],[4,0],[C,0],[D,0],[7,1]]),listl([A,B]),listl([4,C,D]),labeling([ff],[A,B,C,D]).`

It works fine. But when i call `pruefen([[A,0],[1,1],[B,0],[3,0],[_,1],[6,0],[C,0],[D,0],[E,0]]),labeling([ff],[A,B,C,D,E]).`
I run out of stack. So if iam right, the error has to be in filtering the list...

Comment: I am impressed that you managed to describe your puzzle fully as a Prolog term instead of taking the easy way out and writing a parser that builds the term from a "human-readable" representation.

Comment: i had to do it in prolog

Comment: Prolog is a programming language, and, surprisingly, very good at parsing stuff. But this is just a side note.

Comment: @Hans, when you do `listl([A,B,C,8]), print([A,B,C])` are you showing all of the output? I see more than you're showing, which includes the solutions: `A in 6..7\/9, B in 6..7\/9, C in 6..7\/9`. And if you do, `listl([A,B,C,8]), label([A,B,C]).` it will enumerate solutions that include 9 as values for A, B, or C. So I don't see the problem.

Comment: @lurker, i only see the output i already posted, hmm whats wrong. *** u are right. i tried with labeling and i also got the solution with 9!

Comment: @Hans are you using SWI Prolog? What version? I have an older version: 6.0.2. I assume you pressed `;` after the first solution in the `print` scenario?

Comment: @lurker i use swi-prolog version 6.6.6 and i click enter after the print. hmm but when it work with label. i have to find the real problem to solve my puzzle. lurker great help

Comment: If you press Enter after the first solution, it stops looking for more. You need to press `;` to get more solutions. Or Space.

Comment: oh :( u are right. such main things i dont know.

Comment: i checked it: after i created the one dimensional list with my variables only, the domains were deleted... but i dont know how to stop it

Comment: i found, that he run out of stack by labeling the second row: `[_,0],[_,0],[_,1],[_,1],[4,0],[_,0],[_,0],[7,1],[_,1]` he splits up the row and sets the constraints. but on labeling out of stack... trying to find out why now

Comment: `pruefen([[A,0],[B,0],[_,1],[_,1],[4,0],[C,0],[D,0],[7,1],[_,1]]),labeling([ff],[A,B,C,D]).` <-- run out of local stack ; `pruefen([[A,0],[1,1],[B,0],[3,0],[_,1],[6,0],[C,0],[D,0],[E,0]]),labeling([A,B,C,D,E]).` <-- works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I look at str8ts puzzle. The difficulty in this puzzle is to code the fact that there is a set of consecutive numbers, but not ordered !
One way to solve the task is to order the set, and say that the difference between the first and the last number of the list is Len-1 when Len is the length of the list.

This is easy to do when all the numbers of the set are unified, but what can we do when they are not ?

You can post constraint in Prolog whith **when/2** :

So you can say that when all the numbers of Seq will be unified, (e.g. in Prolog : ground(Seq)), you will do what I explained above.

In Prolog you will write :

```
    when(ground(Seq),
         ( sort(Seq, SSeq),
           reverse(SSeq, RSeq),
           SSEq = [F|_],
           RSeq = [L | _],
           L - F =:= Len - 1)))
```

**EDIT** : my solution

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).


str8ts(N) :-
    grille(N, Tableau),
    set_lines(Tableau, Vs1),
    clpfd:transpose(Tableau, R_T),
    set_lines(R_T, Vs2),
    flatten([Vs1, Vs2], Vs),
    label(Vs),
    maplist(writeln, Tableau).




set_lines(Tableau, Vs) :-
    maplist(set_one_line, Tableau, Vs).

set_one_line(Ligne, Vs) :-
    % we fetch forbidden numbers
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^((nonvar(X), X < 0)
             ->  Z = [X | Y]
             ;   Z = Y), Ligne, [], Interdites),
    set_one_line(Ligne, Interdites, [], [], Vs).



% @arg1 : line to study
% @arg2 : list of forbidden numbers for this line
% @arg3 : sequence of variables to unify
% @arg4 : Sequences allready seen
% @arg5 : final list of variables

% Line finished,
% all the numbers of the line must be different
set_one_line([],Forbidden, Tmp_Vs, Cur_Vs, Vs) :-
    flatten( [Tmp_Vs | Cur_Vs], Vs),
    all_distinct(Vs),
    init_sequence(Tmp_Vs,Forbidden).

set_one_line([H|T],Forbidden, Tmp_Vs, Cur_Vs, Vs) :-
    % nonvar must be tested because during backtrack
    % we may have error message :
    % ERROR: H > 0 : Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
    (   var(H); nonvar(H), H > 0),
    set_one_line(T, Forbidden, [H | Tmp_Vs], Cur_Vs, Vs).


set_one_line([H|T],Forbidden, Tmp_Vs, Cur_Vs, Vs) :-
    nonvar(H),
    H =< 0,
    % here we must init a sequence
    init_sequence(Tmp_Vs,Forbidden),
    set_one_line(T, Forbidden, [], [Tmp_Vs |Cur_Vs], Vs).


% the sequence may be empty
init_sequence([], _).

% the sequence may have only one element
init_sequence([X], Forbidden) :-
    maplist(\Y^(X #\= -Y), Forbidden).

init_sequence(L, Forbidden) :-
    set_constraint(L),
        maplist(L +\X^maplist(X +\Y^(Y #\= -X), L), Forbidden).


set_constraint(Line) :-
    length(Line, Len),
    Line ins 1..9,
    all_distinct(Line),
    % we post a contraint on the set of elements
    when(ground(Line),
         (   sort(Line, [H | Tail]),
         reverse([H | Tail], [K |_]),
         K - H =:= Len-1)).


% 142,019,193 inferences, 17.394 CPU in 17.441 seconds (100% CPU, 8164786 Lips)
grille(1,[[0,0,_,_,5,_,_,-3,0],
      [_,6,_,_,0,0,1,_,_],
      [_,_,_,0,-8,_,_,_,_],
      [9,_,_,-4,_,_,_,0,-5],
      [0,_,_,_,_,3,_,_,0],
      [0,0,_,_,_,-9,_,4,_],
      [4,_,3,_,0,0,_,6,_],
      [_,_,1,0,0,_,_,_,_],
      [0,0,8,_,_,_,_,0,-2]]).

% 37,023,520 inferences, 3.900 CPU in 3.916 seconds (100% CPU, 9493149 Lips)
grille(2, [[0,-1,_,_,_,0,_,8,6],
       [_,4,_,_,8,7,_,_,0],
       [_,_,_,0,_,_,_,_,0],
       [0,0,3,_,_,-8,0,_,_],
       [_,_,_,_,1,_,_,_,_],
       [6,_,0,-4,_,_,_,-9,0],
       [-2,_,_,_,9,0,_,_,_],
       [0,_,_,_,_,_,6,_,_],
       [_,_,_,0,_,_,_,0,-3]]).
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, im not sure where to place this predicate. i always get following error: `ERROR: =:=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`

Comment: oh would be great, found one error. was  `SSEq` and not ` SSeq`

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: now i can solve the puzzle only with rows, when i set constraint for column too, i dont find a solution, i will go on find the mistake

Comment: could u explain how to use the lambda libary?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer ! lambda library is use to emulate functionnal style (hope you understand my English !), you can use anonymous function. You can find different examples on the web.